# how to change select box text with your own text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have select options and in values we have

```
        <select name="d11" id="d">
                <option hidden> Next 3 months</option>
                <option value ="3"> Next 3 months</option>
                <option value ="6"> Next 6 Month</option>
                <option value = "12">Next 12 Month</option>
         </select>
```

and with the help of jquery i am able to show change the text on select input box like i need when user click on next 3 month then ***it should show( sep - dec)***
and all according to click.

Problem :

But the problem is this value change when window load and it show the text (Next 3 month) but i want sep - dec and its workig fine if window not load

here is the script

```
         $("#d").change(function() {
            var $this = $( this );
           if (this.value == "3") {

              $this.find( "option:first" ).text( '' + "{{ Date('M 
              Y',strtotime("0 month"))}} - {{ Date('M Y',strtotime("+3 
               month"))}}" ).val("3").prop( 'selected', true )

          }
         else if(this.value == "6")
         {
           $this.find( "option:first" ).text( '' + "{{ Date('M 
          Y',strtotime("0 month"))}} - {{ Date('M Y',strtotime("+6 
          month"))}}" ).val("6").prop( 'selected', true )

         }

     else{
            $this.find( "option:first" ).text( '' + "{{ Date('M 
             Y',strtotime("0 month"))}} - {{ Date('M Y',strtotime("+12 
              month"))}}" ).val("12").prop( 'selected', true )



           }
         } )

window.onload = function() {

var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("6");

$('#d ').val(selItem);

}
$('#d').change(function() { 
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("6", selVal);
});
```

can anybody help

Comment: change event is not triggered when setting value using val().

Comment: You are getting session storage value only on window load. which should be taken when dropdown is changed or you have to set default value in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, selecting a value through the UI is doing what you want, but the onload code to set it to a stored value does not.

That is because the 'change' event is not triggered in that case.

Try:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("6");

    $('#d').val(selItem).trigger('change');

}
```

Comment: it's going into a loop and again and again, refreshing the window

Comment: then post the rest of your code. Nothing in that would reload the page.

Comment: its all my code and I can paste my screenshot here. let me give you an example like I have a select box and when I select next 3 month it shows on window sep-dec and it's correct but when my window reloads then it shows Next 3 month and I don't want to show Next 3 month I want to show sep-dec.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below line of code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#d").change(function () {
                var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
                var $this = $(this);
                var $first = $this.find('option:eq(0)');

                var nextMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
                var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

                if (currentMonth == 11) {
                    nextMonth = 0;
                }

                var requiredMonth = ""

                var text = "";

                if (this.value == "3" || this.value == "6") {
                    if (this.value == "3") {
                        requiredMonth = currentMonth + 3;
                    }
                    else {
                        requiredMonth = currentMonth + 6;
                    }
                    if (requiredMonth > 11) {
                        requiredMonth = requiredMonth - 12;
                    }
                    text = months[nextMonth] + "-" + months[requiredMonth];
                }
                else {
                    text = months[nextMonth] + "-" + months[currentMonth];
                }

                $first.removeAttr('hidden');
                $first.html(text);
                $first.prop('selected', true);
            })
        });

        window.onload = function () {
            $('#d').trigger('change');
        }


 <select name="d11" id="d">
        <option hidden>Next 3 months</option>
        <option value="3">Next 3 months</option>
        <option value="6">Next 6 Month</option>
        <option value="12">Next 12 Month</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: its doing nothing same result let me explain what i want  let me give you an example like I have a select box and when I select next 3 month it shows on window sep-dec and it's correct but when my window reloads then it shows Next 3 month and I don't want to show Next 3 month I want to show sep-dec

Comment: after refreshing window, all the dom object re initialize  again, hence it is sowing next 3 month instead of sep-dec, lemme try if any i can do any solution

Comment: i have updated my code as per your requirement, please let me now if it solves your purpose

Comment: your code this right for simple PHP and I think it will work but I can't use this code in my laravel php . I am working on laravel and it's giving me error as I cant use month directly I need to use Date code as you can see I my code on top. but I am trying to use this code. if you can edit a little more it will be helpful. I am also trying